# Prove Stirling's approximation to factorial

Tags: integration, analysis, approximation, gaussian-integral

Consider
 $$\Gamma(a+1) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x} x^a dx = a!$$
Let 
$$h(u) = (u-1) - \ln(u)$$

then we can write
$$e^{-x} x^a = e^{-a+a\ln(a)}e^{-a~h(x/a)}$$
Expand $h(u)$ in Taylor series at $u=1$
$$h(u) \approx \frac{(u-1)^2}{2}$$
Then we can calculate the integral
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x} x^a dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-a+a\ln(a)}e^{-\frac{a}{2}(\frac{x}{a}-1)^2} dx\\
= a~e^{-a+a\ln(a)} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{a}{2}(u-1)^2} du\\
\approx a~e^{-a+a\ln(a)} \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{a}}=\sqrt{2\pi a} \left( \frac{a}{e} \right)^a
$$
Note that the last integral is gausian integral and when $a \gg 1$ all the area under the curve is concentrated at $u=1$.

However, my question is about approximation $h(u)$ only with leading term,(as we are integrating in higher values of $u$ as well). Why is this valid approximation? Could you show that 
$$ \lim_{a\rightarrow\infty} \frac{I(a) - \tilde{I}(a)}{I(a)}=0$$
where $\tilde{I}(a)$ is the approximated integral, $I(x)$ without approximation. Or give another guarantees for convergence.

And also, is this general method for aproximating integrals? If so, what is the name of this method, and/or where can I read about it?

Thank you.

Comment: The Taylor series only converges on a small interval, how is it justified using it on $[0,\infty)$?